# in what case does bindService return false?

Tags: android, android-context

I was wondering when does `Context.bindService()` return `false`?

I've tried to make the `onBind()` return `null`, but it still returns `true` when `bindService` is called and the `onServiceConnected` does not get executed.  I also saw this on Google Groups with no response
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ZLl56Mz1jYg

I also can't find the implementation of bindService, since it is abstract in Context.java and searching for "public boolean bindService" does not yield any useful results either (closest was ApplicationContext which does not seem to be present in the current API levels).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The implementation of binderService  is in [android.app.ConntextImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.bindService%28android.content.Intent,android.content.ServiceConnection,int%29):

```
1412    public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags, int userHandle) {
1413        IServiceConnection sd;
1414        if (conn == null) {
1415            throw new IllegalArgumentException("connection is null");
1416        }
1417        if (mPackageInfo != null) {
1418            sd = mPackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(conn, getOuterContext(),
1419                    mMainThread.getHandler(), flags);
1420        } else {
1421            throw new RuntimeException("Not supported in system context");
1422        }
1423        try {
1424            IBinder token = getActivityToken();
1425            if (token == null && (flags&BIND_AUTO_CREATE) == 0 && mPackageInfo != null
1426                    && mPackageInfo.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
1427                    < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
1428                flags |= BIND_WAIVE_PRIORITY;
1429            }
1430            service.setAllowFds(false);
1431            int res = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().bindService(
1432                mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), getActivityToken(),
1433                service, service.resolveTypeIfNeeded(getContentResolver()),
1434                sd, flags, userHandle);
1435            if (res < 0) {
1436                throw new SecurityException(
1437                        "Not allowed to bind to service " + service);
1438            }
1439            return res != 0;
1440        } catch (RemoteException e) {
1441            return false;
1442        }
1443    }
```

From line 1431, you can see it calls ActivityManagerNative's bindService.
This implementation is in [com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java):

```
11070    public int bindService(IApplicationThread caller, IBinder token,
11071        Intent service, String resolvedType,
11072        IServiceConnection connection, int flags, int userId) {
11073        enforceNotIsolatedCaller("bindService");
11074        // Refuse possible leaked file descriptors
11075        if (service != null && service.hasFileDescriptors() == true) {
11076            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File descriptors passed in Intent");
11077        }
11078
11079        synchronized(this) {
11080            return mServices.bindServiceLocked(caller, token, service, resolvedType,
11081                connection, flags, userId);
11082        }
11083    }
```

so it finally calls the bindeServiceLocked of [com.android.server.am.ActiveServices](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/server/am/ActiveServices.java#ActiveServices.bindServiceLocked%28android.app.IApplicationThread,android.os.IBinder,android.content.Intent,java.lang.String,android.app.IServiceConnection,int,int%29).

**Update:**

By reading the code of binderServiceLocked():

```
472         ServiceLookupResult res =
473             retrieveServiceLocked(service, resolvedType,
474                     Binder.getCallingPid(), Binder.getCallingUid(), userId, true);
475         if (res == null) {
476             return 0;
477         }
478         if (res.record == null) {
479             return -1;
480         }
```

Found that if result of retrieveServiceLocked() is null, it will return false.
SAfter checking the code of retrieveServiceLocked()

```
721                 ResolveInfo rInfo =
722                     AppGlobals.getPackageManager().resolveService(
723                                 service, resolvedType,
724                                 ActivityManagerService.STOCK_PM_FLAGS, userId);
725                 ServiceInfo sInfo =
726                     rInfo != null ? rInfo.serviceInfo : null;
727                 if (sInfo == null) {
728                     Slog.w(TAG, "Unable to start service " + service + " U=" + userId +
729                           ": not found");
730                     return null;
731                 }
```

Found that If can't get the ResolveInfo of Service, it will false.

So I tried to **remove** the **Service declaration** in **AndroidManifest.xml** and find that the bindService() return false.

Comment: looking through the source of ActiveServices it seems to accept null binders and just return ok.  Kind of odd.

Comment: Please see my update, I found one case that bindService() will return false

Answer (score 7):

One very common case in which bindService returns false is if the service was not [declared in the Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Declaring).
In that case you should add code like seen below to your manifest file

```
<manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also it happens when you try to call **BindService** of stopped activity (onStop called already)

Comment: Thank YOU!  For others, using the applications context instead of the activity's context can fix this.  activity.getApplicationContext()