# BindService() call fails on Android Marshmallow Device (just one user)

Tags: android, security, permissions, system, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app on the google play store with ~7000 users, its a graphing plugin app for a popular automotive monitoring app called "Torque Pro". I have one user on a Pendo Pad tablet w/ Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow) where the bindservice() call to a remote service returns false. I have many other users on all version that are running w/o any issue, just one user stuck with this problem.

My app binds to a remote service (torque plugin service) in another process. Code is below, works fine as I said for all other users and on my test devices (Android V2.3.1, V4.4, V5.1).

I am assuming that this an app permission issue or security issue w/ Marshmallow. Hoping someone knows the setting to fix this.

Thanks for the help,

Phil

```
public void doBindService() {

    try {

        // Bind to the torque service
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        String pkg = "org.prowl.torque";
        String cls = "org.prowl.torque.remote.TorqueService";

        intent.setPackage(pkg);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
        intent.setClassName(pkg, cls);

        if (!mIsBound) {
            boolean status = bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            if (status == false) {
                toast("RTC Error - Bind failed to Torque Pro Service", PluginActivity.this);
            } else {
                mIsBound = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        popupMessage("RTC Bind Service Exception", "Exception while binding to Torque Pro Service.",
                false, handler, PluginActivity.this);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your error?

Comment: why `setPackage` and `setComponent` and `setClassName` ? one is enough... (at least 2nd or 3rd) - actually i have no idea how it will work with `setPackage`...

Comment: Yes, the 2nd and 3rd set calls are redundant, I only had the setClassName() call in the code (works fine) until this issue occurred. I put the other calls in recently just in case after I saw those being used in other stackoverflow examples. This is my latest code so I decided to post that as the example.

Comment: @dima I don't have access to the Pendo device, the user is in Australia and I am in the USA so I can't attach a debugger.

Comment: Found the bindService() source code in other post, I am guessing that the remote service (not my code) is taking an exception for some reason and bindservice() is returning false from the catch block..   

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780049/in-what-case-does-bindservice-return-false