# Remote Service - Unable to start service Intent U=0 not found

Tags: android, service

I have a socket service

## Manifest

```
<service
    android:name=".SocketService"
    android:process=":socket"/>
```

I connect to it through `bindService`
and use `AIDL`

The service is designed to exchange data with the server and the application. The service does not have the intent-filters.

```
public final class SocketService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new Binder();
    }
    private final class Binder extends ISocketService.Stub {
        @Override
        public void on(String event, ISocketEmitterListener listener) throws RemoteException {
            ...
        }
        @Override
        public int emit(String event, byte[] bytes) throws RemoteException {
            ...
            return 0;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        boolean stopSelf = DBManager.getBoolean(DBManager.SOCKET_SERVICE_STOP_SELF);
        if (stopSelf) {
            stopSelf();
            DBManager.save(DBManager.SOCKET_SERVICE_STOP_SELF, false);
        }
        Timber.i("SocketService unbinded!");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Timber.i("SocketService started!");
        ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        stopSelf();
        Timber.i("SocketService task removed!");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        DBManager.save(DBManager.SOCKET_SERVICE_IS_RUNNING, false);
        Timber.i("SocketService destroyed!");
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the application receives any error and crashes, or just closes incorrectly, for example, it is unloaded by the user through the task manager, the next service launch is impossible! To do this, you need to reinstall the application otherwise it writes this:
`ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=package.name/.SocketService} U=0: not found`

How to get rid of this **WITHOUT REINSTALL APPLICATION** ?

I have already tried many ways:
1) Override `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` and do there undind and stopService before `System.exit(1)`
2) Ovveride `onTaskRemoved()` with `stopSelf()` inside
3) Etc...

Now I have made such a method for checking, so that if anything to inform the user that he must reinstall the application because of this error.

```
public static boolean checkOnNonNull(Context context, Class<?> clazz) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, clazz);
    ResolveInfo rInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveService(service, PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES);
    ServiceInfo sInfo = rInfo != null ? rInfo.serviceInfo : null;
    if (sInfo == null) {
        Timber.e("Unable to start service " + service + ": not found");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

***UPD***
I conducted some tests and it turns out as if the record from the manifest really disappears, because I started adding numbers to the class name and the service started working with an already new name. But all the old names were not found.

```
<service
    android:name=".SocketService+[1-10]"
    android:process=":socket"/>
// Then I put the numbers in reverse order and .SocketService9 useded once already not found.
```

Comment: I read about a similar problem, which is closer to my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780049/in-what-case-does-bindservice-return-false/17781118#17781118

Answer (score 0):

The only working option when the service is disabled as a component is to turn it on manually:

```
public static boolean checkOnNonNull(Context context, Class<?> clazz) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, clazz);
    ResolveInfo rInfo = context.getPackageManager().resolveService(service, PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES);
    ServiceInfo sInfo = rInfo != null ? rInfo.serviceInfo : null;
    if (sInfo == null) {
        Timber.e("Unable to start service " + service + ": not found");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (!checkOnNonNull(context, MyServiceClass.class)) {
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyServiceClass.class.getName());
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
}
```